# jQuery select box with disable-able options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, select

I'm looking for a jQuery/JavaScript select box for my HTML forms. The specific requirement in my case is that I need to be able to disable certain options in the control's menu. I'd like to know if anyone has found a plugin that allows me to do this, preferably easily by using something like

```
$("#selectControl").change(function()
{
    $(this).find(":selected").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Of course, the `attr()` function won't work on a generated element, but is there a jQuery plugin that has a wrapper for this functionality?

**EDIT**

To make myself clearer, I'll say it differently: I have an HTML structure that looks like a nicely styled select box, with the hidden actual `<select>` control behind it. It's possible to disable an `<option>` in the `<select>`, but not in most jQuery plugins for styling select boxes. I'm asking if there is a plugin out there that *will* allow me to disable certain options in the prettified `<select>` element.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Disabled and selected are actually properties not attributes, as updated in jQuery 1.6. Check out the prop() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Thanks for that, but you've missed the point of my question. I've edited to make myself clearer - sorry.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't know of any off-hand but jQuery is extremely versatile and you should be able to extend any plugin you're currently using to support disabling options. Can you make a jsbin or jsfiddle page or provide a link to your example so I can see the plugin code?

Comment: No problem. I'm currently using this plugin: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/ I'll definitely look into extending it. I was just wondering if there was already a plugin out and about so I wouldn't have to rewrite features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I didn't look hard enough. For those who want the same thing as myself, I found [this plugin](https://github.com/revsystems/jQuery-SelectBox). To get my "disable on select" behaviour, I used the jQuery tie plugin which is linked to on the page in the URL somewhere. This is a bit of a hefty selectbox plugin, but minified it should be fine. The box is styled very easily with CSS and can be done entirely without images using the border width trick. If I get enough interest, I'll write a tutorial on how to style these boxes.

**EDIT**

The plugin linked above didn't actually work very well, so I just wrote my own. I'll post a link to it some time if anyone wants to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm tracking on your question, but the code snippet below operates on a dropdown, to hide certain options:

```
//show them all
$('#<%= ddlRank.ClientID %> span').each(
    function () {
        var opt = $(this).find("option").show();
         $(this).replaceWith(opt);
    }
);

//hide unrelated
var selectionLost = false;
$('#<%= ddlRank.ClientID %> option').each(
    function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), related) == -1) {
            if ($(this).attr("selected")) {
                $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                selectionLost = true;
            }
            $(this).wrap("<span>").hide();
        }
    }
);
```

The secret sauce (to hide them, in conjunction with the "show all" code) is:

```
$(this).wrap("<span>").hide();
```